# C# nullable and FirstOrDefault failure

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

I have a null list and attempting a FirstOrDefault behaves differently in different coding styles. Trying to undersand the difference.
The below three snippets attempt the same thing. But ans3 alone works without any exception. Aren't ans2 and ans3 the same?

```
        IList<int> list = null;

        var ans1 = list.FirstOrDefault(); //Fails

        var temp = list?.ToList();
        var ans2 = temp.FirstOrDefault(); //Fails

        var ans3 = list?.ToList().FirstOrDefault(); //Passes
```

Comment: How are `ans2` and `ans3` the same?

Comment: "*Aren't ans2 and ans3 the same*" - no.. This is about the time we read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-

Comment: I suggest you take a look in [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI4DcyamcALOUhQMyYzoDC6A3suj5k1NXQBZABQBKTt17SAkgQDOAFwA8RRQD50AG3xL0AXnSEArlq11p0gG4BDAE7obheXAPbdi7ADF8dpQHk7ABEAUwAzG1NFcVJ0AHo4rxt8LXkpHgBfdPRsqH5BADlxSSRLXjkPVUINdz1DEzMLMvRbB0UQgFsABzcdJQB+bAAVAHsFaLEmstbHZxZDdu7vXwDg8MitCdiEpJS00t4sg55c/PR/Yq5jywqlKpq+xTcG82ls63tZ+SZDR8HR8biZZ+RSBUIRKIxeJxAAKNnk8hC8jK2SOGSAA===).

Comment: Note that `var ans3 = (list?.ToList()).FirstOrDefault()` _would_ be equivalent to `ans2`. I mean, you wouldn't do that - but including it for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 8):

> Aren't ans2 and ans3 the same?

They aren't: The null conditional operator `?.` halts the left-to-right evaluation of a chained sequence at the first null it encounters and resolves the whole expression to null

- `ans1` fails because you call a method on a `null`. This crashes
- `ans2` fails because `list` is null, the `?.` sees that it is null and resolves the expression to null (`ToList()` is never called) so `null` is stored in `temp`. You then try and call `FirstOrDefault` on a `null` `temp`, which crashes for the same reason as the `ans1` attempt
- `ans3` passes because neither `ToList` or `FirstOrDefault` are ever called. `ans3` is set to null as soon as C# discovers `list` is null

You could use `??` in combiantion with `?.` to ensure that items have a value:

```
var temp = list?.ToList() ?? new List<Thing>();
```

If `?.` inspects `list` and finds it to be null, then the `list?.ToList()` resolves to `null`. `??` will then act, ensuring that the expression resolves to an empty `List` instead. This would be safe to call methods on..

Null conditional can be used more than once:

```
ans3 = someObject?.Any?.Of()?.These?.PropsOrMethods?.Could()?.Be?.Null
```

If any property or method in that chain returned `null`, the whole thing is `null` as soon as thenull is encountered, no matter where it was in the chain. If the null thing was `These`, then nothing after it would be called